# Git command not working in VS Code terminal/cmd/powershell

Tags: git, powershell, visual-studio-code, cmd, windows-11

I correctly installed GIT, but vs code command prompt responds:

"Git is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file."

After adding:

```
"git.enabled": true,
"git.path": "C:\\'Program Files'\\Git\\mingw64\\bin\\git.exe",
```

it still won't work. Even after closing and opening vs code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454769/what-is-the-reason-for-x-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) Remove also both `'` in `git.path` string value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using escaped double-quotes in your `.json` file, *instead of adding single-quotes, which do not exist within the path a all*?

```json
  "git.path": "\"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\bin\\git.exe\"",
```

Comment: or try adding `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin` to PATH in System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables

Comment: I would never advise that, @JuniorMayhé. There is no need ever to add any location to your one of your `Path` variables, and I do not advocate it. Also that would ne a GUI fix, and the question was clearly looking for a fix within their JSON.

Answer (score -1):

If vs code doesn't close your internal command prompt and reopens with it again, you have to close the cmd manually.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that the change only takes effect in _future_ shells running in VS Code's integrate terminal, correct?

Comment: Also, it's not clear _what file_ you've added the lines in your question to.